# Google Tag Manager tags do not fire if I do not go to the page url directly for wix sites

Tags: google-analytics, triggers, google-tag-manager, velo

I used Wix to build my website and now I connected it to Google Tag Manager to initiate an event when a user scrolls 50% and spends 1 minute on the website. I am facing 2 issues, and I am pretty sure both of them will be fixed simultaneously.

1. Scroll depth trigger is only fired once. So, I wish to track this event for all my blog posts and have set it up accordingly. Now, if I go to any page on my website, but do not scroll down, and then go to any blog post and scroll, the tag and trigger work perfectly fine. However, if on any other page, other than the blog post, I scroll down and the scroll depth is fired, and then I go to any blog post, and scroll on that, it does not fire.
2. The tag that includes scroll depth and timer triggers fires only if I directly go to the blog post. So, if I go to my landing page, then go to a blog post from there, the tag does not fire. However, if I directly go to the URL of the post, it fires.

I have done a fair amount of research regarding what could cause this issue and below are the following things I have tried. Also, I guess the issue is due to the Wix websites being SPA, so the code loads only once.

1. I have tried to implement the history change and Page view trigger to fire a tag so that a change is registered. Does not work
2. I have tried using luna-scroll-tracking since I read [here](https://mixedanalytics.com/blog/scroll-tracking-single-page-applications-gtm/) that this should help with the scroll bit. Does not work as well. Basically, with this script, the trigger for the scroll is fired as soon as the window loads. So, in reality, when I scroll, no trigger is fired.

I am really really fed up due to this. Can someone please help? I have attached all the relevant screenshots below.

[image: Scroll for blog] [image: Timer for blog] [image: Trigger group for blog] [image: Blog tag] [image: history change and page view trigger]

Another thing, when I add the history change trigger, for some reason, with one page change, it is fired twice. Idk why. See below for the change in data layer. I hope you can help me with this as well.

1st fire:

```
{
  gtm: {
    start: 1615183444614,
    uniqueEventId: 6,
    scrollThreshold: 50,
    scrollUnits: 'percent',
    scrollDirection: 'vertical',
    triggers: '41346941_8',
    historyChangeSource: 'replaceState',
    oldUrlFragment: '',
    newUrlFragment: '',
    oldHistoryState: null,
    newHistoryState: {scrollY: 0},
    oldUrl: 'https://www.joinrealtalk.co/?gtm_debug=x',
    newUrl: 'https://www.joinrealtalk.co/?gtm_debug=x'
  },
  event: 'gtm.historyChange',
  url: '/?gtm_debug=x',
  title: 'RealTalk | Mental Health Peer Support App'
}
```

2nd fire:

```
{
  gtm: {
    start: 1615183444614,
    uniqueEventId: 8,
    scrollThreshold: 50,
    scrollUnits: 'percent',
    scrollDirection: 'vertical',
    triggers: '41346941_8',
    historyChangeSource: 'pushState',
    oldUrlFragment: '',
    newUrlFragment: '',
    oldHistoryState: {scrollY: 0},
    newHistoryState: null,
    oldUrl: 'https://www.joinrealtalk.co/?gtm_debug=x',
    newUrl: 'https://www.joinrealtalk.co/blog'
  },
  event: 'gtm.historyChange',
  url: '/?gtm_debug=x',
  title: 'RealTalk | Mental Health Peer Support App'
}
```

Comment: Trigger groups are only fired once: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/trigger-groups-google-tag-manager/#trigger-groups-will-fire-just-once

Comment: Hey, I got that. But that is not what is causing the problem here. The entire problem is, if I am going to a URL indirectly, the tag fires, otherwise does not. "The tag that includes scroll depth and timer triggers fires only if I directly go to the blog post. So, if I go to my landing page, then go to a blog post from there, the tag does not fire. However, if I directly go to the URL of the post, it fires.'

Answer (score 0):

Concept :
WIX websites are coded as single-page applications. Even though it looks like pages are being reloaded while you’re navigating, that’s just an illusion.

My solution might be not directly answer your issue but worth to try to fix the trigger issue.

So you need to create a custom trigger event and the value must be corresponding with the one found in your variable value.

Good Luck
SS